# "Can't open PID file" after renamed JBoss host on RHEL

Tags: jboss, rhel

A colleague recreated a JBoss server on RHEL by copying an existing standalone.xml file from another server.  After I renamed the server (near the top of standalone.xml) from "abc-demo" to "abc" I started getting

```
jboss-eap-rhel.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/jboss-eap/jboss-eap.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
```

when I start the service.  How do I overcome this?  If I put a number into the pid file (which doesn't exist) the file is removed on startup.

I believe our RHEL and JBoss both use the most recent versions.

Comment: You should be asking this question on superuser, not stackoverflow. https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Once I looked into the JBoss log it described an error.  After significant squinting I found an error in standalone.xml that was causing JBoss to fail starting up which was seen shown as the "can't find pid file" error above from the perspective of the service startup.